# Eigen Reorder Rows without Copy

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

How can you reorder the rows (or columns) of an `Eigen` matrix without copying them? You can use `Eigen::Map` to reshape them without copying the data, so I'm assuming there is some way to change the ordering as well, but there does not seem to be an example in the documentation.

Comment: `Eigen::Map` can reshape without copying because it doesn't need to reorder anything, just interpret the array differently. That isn't applicable to permuting rows or columns.

Comment: `swap` seems to be quick (see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply your matrix by a [`PermutationMatrix`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PermutationMatrix.html), or by a [`Transpositions` matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transpositions.html). If you multiply `P * A`, then the rows of `A` are permuted according to the indexes in `P`. The product itself is lazy, i.e., it is only evaluated when needed (however, there are no strong guarantees when temporaries are constructed, when evaluating more complex expressions).